# Roblox TextBox display value is not the same as the value in the editor

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I have a `TextBox` in a `ScreenGui` inside `StarterGui`. I've created a script that sets a variable named `cash` to 10. It should then procede to change the value of `TextBox` to 10; it does. Then, 1 second later, it increases `cash` by 10, and changes the value of `TextBox` to 20, but didn't display it. I then looked in the editor, and sure enough, it said **20** as the value.

Why was it displaying the original value, and not the ***actual*** value?

[image]

Comment: provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've selected the wrong TextBox. It is selected in your properties menu, but it is not highlighted on the screen. Maybe you're looking at the TextBox in the StarterGui? So that could be the problem with your script.